# How to work with gotext extract if I use go.mod?

Tags: go

1. `mkdir getexttest`
2. `cd getexttest`
3. `cat main.go`

```
    package main

    import (
        "golang.org/x/text/language"
        "golang.org/x/text/message"
    )

    func main() {
        message.NewPrinter(language.English).Printf("Hello, World")
    }
```

4. `go get -u golang.org/x/text/cmd/gotext`
5. `gotext extract .` **WORKS FINE**
6. `go mod init getexttest`
7. `gotext extract .` **!!!DOESN'T WORK!!!**

Errors:

```
/home/alex/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.2/language/coverage.go:11:2: could not import golang.org/x/text/internal/language (go/build: importGo golang.org/x/text/internal/language: exit status 1
error writing go.mod: open /home/alex/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.2/go.mod298498081.tmp: permission denied
...
...
gotext: extract failed: : : couldn't load packages due to errors: golang.org/x/text/message, golang.org/x/text/language
```

**How to work with gotext extract if I use mod.go?**

Comment: Same here. Have you ever got it to work? https://github.com/golang/text/pull/9 doesn't seem to get looked at by golang maintainers...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `GO111MODULE=off` in the environment variables. It might fix this issue.

Comment: yes, for the example above, disabling GO111MODULE works. But the real project is more complicated, for example, using github.com/urfave/cli/v2, and if GO111MODULE is disabled, another error appears: "could not import github.com/urfave/cli/v2". And "go get" does not work for "v2".

Comment: I know very little about the modules that you are working with. But I think `text` package doesn't have go modules support `https://github.com/golang/text/pull/9`